# OpenStreetMap is more technical than many people think

Tags: openstreetmap, ogc

I have been asked to write an article on the above topic. I am writing on

1. Quasi topological data format
2. Incompatibility with OGC standards (WMS vs mapnik, WFS vs overpass, SLD vs mapcss)
3. Closed nature (you require different tools to process data)
4. Attribute model (hstore model)

Is there something i am missing? and are there already such articles.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an answerable question. It is highly subjective and better suited for a forum.

Comment: Please rephrase the title into a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book [OpenStreetMap: Using and Enhancing the Free Map of the World](http://www.openstreetmap.info/) by Ramm, Topf & Chilton covers these issues at length. Maybe asking on [osm-professional](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/osm-professional) might spark useful discussion and pointers, too.

The OpenStreetMap data model is entirely user driven, and I'm paraphrasing a half-remembered quote here, “… the simplest we could come up with to make a map of the world”. I think of it as a map that changes constantly, rather than an intentional GIS. The OGC model is just a model with its own limitations and caveats — and I don't think anyone could rightfully say it was the “simplest” at anything.

I'd also disagree that the OSM tools are in any way closed; they're as open as anything else in the OGC realm. They often started as tools to fill the author's needs, not to fulfil some grand overarching plan.